# How to enable shortcuts for the Node Wrangler add-on on macbook?

Tags: node-editor, add-on, shortcut

Having some troubles with activating Node Wrangler on mac,
seems like short cuts for the add-on are not functional.
I am sure there are users of mac who has already solved this problem,

Comment: Try Shift+W in the shader editor. It should give you the Node Wrangler menu with options and shortcuts.

Comment: Note that the node wrangler shortcuts do not support the Command (⌘) as a substitute for Control. Shortcuts that use the Control key do not work with the Command key.

Answer (score 1):

Try disableing it and then re-enable it. Do restart in method. 
i'm using MAC and it never showed me any error. It worked smoothly.

just pressed Ctrl+Shift and click on any node.

What is appearing in "Quick Access" in "N" menu under "Node Wrangler" options, in your Blender Node Editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Command</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd> on a Mac to add the *Texture Coordinate* and *Mapping* nodes.

Comment: On Mac, there is no control key, but a `command` key.